# Webpack building unchanged files and taking too much time overall

Tags: webpack

I don't have much experience in webpack so I don't know if this is normal but webpack seems to build all of my files even those I didn't modify everytime

So the build time becomes increasingly long as my projects grow (7 seconds and more)

It can be quite frustrating to wait 7 seconds for every small change I make

Here's my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/browser/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Components: __dirname + '/src/browser/components',
      Actions: __dirname + '/src/browser/actions',
      Reducers: __dirname + '/src/browser/reducers',
      Utils: __dirname + '/src/utils'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test:  /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  stats: {
    warnings: false
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

Comment: You mean, when you run `webpack -p` this bundles everything?? Yeah, that is the normal behaviour, no way to work around that. Webpack cant know which files were changed, without being too expensive to perform that type of thing.